# How to refer to the CodeName of a Excel sheet from word?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want to use the CodeName of an Excel sheet in a Word macro. However, in Word, the property seems not working.

This piece works:

```
Dim sht As Object
Dim xlsobj_2 As Object
Dim sheetName As String

Set xlsobj_2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlsobj_2.Application.Visible = True 'I can see it opens as I expected.
Set xlsfile = xlsobj_2.Application.Workbooks.Open(folder & fileName, UpdateLinks:=0) 'You can create your own excel file.
Set sht = xlsfile.Sheets(sheetName)  
MsgBox sht.Name 'This gives me the name of the sheet and I know it is correct.
```

This which is what I want does not work:

```
Dim sht As Object
Dim sheetName As String
Dim sheetName As String

...'Same as above.

MsgBox sht.CodeName
```

Thank you smart people!

Comment: It seems to work for me, so it might be due to the way you have declared `sht`.  Can you include all the relevant parts of your code (e.g. your `Dim` statements, the setting of the Excel Application object, and the setting of the workbook object.)

Comment: "does not work" is not a useful description of your problem.  What happens when you run that code?

Comment: Word VBA always changes the "C" in "CodeName" to lowercase c. And when I run, the MsgBox gives nothing.

Comment: FWIW `xlsobj_2.Application.` should be just `xlsobj_2.`. (`xlsobj_2` is an `Application` object, so you don't need to reference the Application's Application.)  But that shouldn't cause your problem because I ran you code as posted and it worked for me.

Comment: The lowercase c in `codeName` is probably caused by typing it that way at some stage, or having a variable called `codeName`, and it has just "remembered" that as the case for it - it shouldn't be an issue.  (I just tested by doing a `Dim codeName As String`, then deleting that line again, and now I am stuck with `codeName` as the property name - but the code still runs OK.)

Comment: I have not changed anything except for closing and reopening since last run, and now it works!  @YowE3K : I appreciate your help and wish great people like you all the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A worksheet is only assigned a `CodeName` when you go into the Visual Basic Editor for the first time after the sheet is created.  (And, obviously, you will need to save the workbook again after having done so.)

Until the `CodeName` is assigned, the `.CodeName` property will return an empty string.

---

The effect of this is often confusing.  For example, if you open a new workbook with the default 3 empty worksheets, and then you immediately insert another worksheet before the first one, and **then** go into VBE, you will have

- Worksheets("Sheet4") having a `Name` of `"Sheet4"` and a `CodeName` of `Sheet1`
- Worksheets("Sheet1") having a `Name` of `"Sheet1"` and a `CodeName` of `Sheet2`
- Worksheets("Sheet2") having a `Name` of `"Sheet2"` and a `CodeName` of `Sheet3`
- Worksheets("Sheet3") having a `Name` of `"Sheet3"` and a `CodeName` of `Sheet4`

Comment: A follow up: It seems that in order for the CodeName to have value in word VBE, VBE in Excel where the object is has to be opened.